# Array of object deep comparison with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, lodash

I've 2 array of objects that I'd deeply compare with `lodash`

However, I've a prob with it:

```
> var x = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}];
> var y = [{b:2, a:1}, {d:4, c:3}];
> _.difference(x,y, _.isEqual);
[ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3, d: 4 } ]
```

How should I compare to see that both are equal?

Comment: Array of arrays is possible to sort. Array of objects is not.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can make use of [differenceWith()](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith) with an [isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) comparator, and invoke [isEmpty](https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty) to check if they are equal or not.

```js
var isArrayEqual = function(x, y) {
  return _(x).differenceWith(y, _.isEqual).isEmpty();
};

var result1 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}],
  [{b:2, a:1}, {d:4, c:3}]
);

var result2 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2, c: 1}, {c:3, d:4}],
  [{b:2, a:1}, {d:4, c:3}]
);

document.write([
  '<div><label>result1: ', result1, '</label></div>',
  '<div><label>result2: ', result2, '</label></div>',
].join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE June 22, 2018**

This update is in response to the comment below:

> @ryeballar if any of the array is undefined it returns true. How would
>   you solve this. Thanks in advance buddy

As stated in the `differenceWith` documentation:

> The order and references of result values are determined by the first
>   array.

This means that as long as all the items in the first array will match everything else in the second array, then the resulting array from the `differenceWith` invocation will be empty.

An alternative solution that truly solves the problem is to use [`xorWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#xorWith) with the same chain of functions from the solution above.

```js
var isArrayEqual = function(x, y) {
  return _(x).xorWith(y, _.isEqual).isEmpty();
};

var result1 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}],
  [{b:2, a:1}, {d:4, c:3}]
);

var result2 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2, c: 1}, {c:3, d:4}],
  [{b:2, a:1}, {d:4, c:3}]
);

var result3 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2, c: 1}, {c:3, d:4}],
  [{b:2, a:1}, {d:4, c:3}, undefined]
);

console.log('result1:', result1);
console.log('result2:', result2);
console.log('result3:', result3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @ryeballar . Basically I really need to find `diff` between them, so `_.difference` should be just replaced with `_.differenceWith` with `_.isEqual` comparator.

Comment: I've never seen syntax for `_(foo)` mentioned anywhere in lodash.

Where is this in the docs?

Comment: @DonP You may refer to [this part of the lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#lodash).

Comment: @ryeballar if any of the array is undefined it returns true. How would you solve this. Thanks in advance buddy

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto I added an update, this answer is already quite outdated.

Comment: @ryeballar , could you show, how I can achieve `_(x)` with individually installed components, because I do not need the whole `lodash`? I found `lodash.isequal` (ie `npm i --save lodash.isequal`), `lodash.xorwith`, `lodash.isequal`, `lodash.isempty`, but I do not know what to install for `_(x)`.

Comment: You can simply require each function and then use them as you would in a non-chained manner. `isEmpty(xorWith(x, y, isEqual))`

Comment: How about `IsEmpty(differenceWith(x,y,IsEqual))  && isEmpty(differenceWith(y,x,IsEqual))`?  Looks easier to write, regardless of whether it takes two iterations instead of one.  Simplicity might make it faster for small cases anyway.

Answer (score 32):

Following @ryeballar answer, if you only want to import specific lodash methods you can use this notation:

```
import { isEmpty, isEqual, xorWith } from 'lodash';


export const isArrayEqual = (x, y) => isEmpty(xorWith(x, y, isEqual));
```

Comment: nice solution, thanks

Comment: awesome thanks there is codesandbox for it  https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-fog-30b7d1?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue

Comment:  this answer; TY so much. Called mine `isEquivalent`, as you can actually pass any two arrays/objects/values/...

Answer (score 6):

Both answers on above with `xorWith` & `differenceWith` do not take in count if the array has different length only if the current item is found in the second array.

```js
var isArrayEqual = function(x, y) {
  return _(x).xorWith(y, _.isEqual).isEmpty();
};

var result = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2}],
  [{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}]
);


console.log('result should be false:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In that particular case, we also would have to compare both arrays length.

```js
const isArrayEqual = function(x, y) {
  const isSameSize = _.size(x) === _.size(y);
  return isSameSize && _(x).xorWith(y, _.isEqual).isEmpty();
};

const result = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2}],
  [{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}]
);


console.log('result should be false:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for including this check. You can get false-positives with the others.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer pure JS since i haven't got the patience to learn underscore or lodash. So i invent something i have been long dreaming of. The `Object.prototype.compare()`. The v0.0.2 is doing only shallow comparison though but adequate for this question.

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
var obj1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3},
    obj2 = {c:3,a:1,b:2},
    obj3 = {b:2,c:3,a:7};

document.write ("<pre>" + obj1.compare(obj2) + "</pre>\n");
document.write ("<pre>" + obj2.compare(obj3) + "</pre>\n");
document.write ("<pre>" + new Object({a:1, b:2, c:3}).compare({c:3,b:2,a:1,d:0}) + "</pre>\n");
```

Cool... So then lets continue with the question... I guess... since we already have an `Object.prototype.compare()` there should be absolutely no harm in the invention of `Array.prototype.compare()`. Lets make it more clever this time. It shall tell primitives from objects. One other thing is, arrays are ordered; so in my book `[1,2]` is not equal to `[2,1]`. Also this makes the job simpler.

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
Array.prototype.compare = function(a){
  return this.every((e,i) => typeof a[i] === "object" ? a[i].compare(e) : a[i] === e);
}
var x = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}],
    y = [{b:2, a:1}, {d:4, c:3}],
    a = [1,2,3,4,5],
    b = [1,2,3,4,5],
    p = "fourtytwo",
    r = "thirtyseven",
    n = 42,
    m = 37;
document.writeln(x.compare(y)); // the question is answered here
document.writeln(a.compare(b));
document.writeln(p.compare(r)); // these primitives end up at Object prototype
document.writeln(n.compare(m)); // so modify Object.prototype.compare () accordingly
```

Comment: Your solution looks cool, thanks. However:

`new Object({a:1, b:2, c:3}).compare({c:3,b:2,a:1,d:0});`
returns `true`, but should be `false`

Same problems with deep object comparison. I'd prefer existing `lodash` solution.

Comment: @Archer: hmm cool.. that's why it's v0.0.1. Seems we have to add a check for `Object.keys().length` stage too.

Comment: @Archer: did a quick fix. I guess next stage could be to make it dive deeper recursively, hand to hand with it's twin `Array.prototype.compare()`

Comment: good ;) But better to learn `lodash`. It's what it was designed for.

Comment: @Archer Well may be... But I am a very library agnostic person. Think it this way, if you need a banana you wouldn't like a gorilla knocking at your door holding a banana with the whole jungle behind...

Comment: Sometime you need many different fruits and gorilla might get them to you... Better this way rather then plant all those fruits yourself.

Comment: Nice effort but there's a god-like term for these cases: 'Don't reinvent the wheel'. Anyway, javascript es6 should natively include array and object comparisons with shallow and deep flags in my humble opinion.

Comment: How can I use your method in Angular with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Combining answers from [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57166363/4672396) & [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68888638/4672396), with examples.

```js
const isArrayEqual = (x, y) => (
_.size(x) === _.size(y) && _.isEmpty(_.xorWith(x, y, _.isEqual))
);

const result1 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2}],
  [{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}]
);

const result2 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2},{a:2, b:2}],
  [{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}]
);

const result3 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:1, b:2},{a:1, b:2}],
  [{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}]
);

// if order is changed
const result4 = isArrayEqual(
  [{a:2, b:2},{a:1, b:2}],
  [{a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:2}]
);

console.log('result1 should be false:', result1);
console.log('result2 should be false:', result2);
console.log('result3 should be true:', result3);
console.log('result4 should be true:', result4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In Js solutions, one line code :

```
import { size, isEmpty, isEqual, xorWith } from "lodash";    
export const isArrayOfObjectsEqual = (x, y) => size(x) === size(y) && isEmpty(xorWith(x, y, isEqual));
```