# Get the difference between next-props and props

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Basically, i want to find difference in between nextprops and nextState. both are contains an array with the objects.
if any different between props then i will add that particular props to the state.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {

}
```

i was able to find npm package call **react-addons-shallow-compare** but it doesn't work for me. please find the code below.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("nextProps.workers && this.state.fetchAction ",prevProps," && ",prevState);
    let status = shallowCompare(this, prevProps, prevState);
    console.log("status ",status);

}
```

Every time it return true. even if props are two different. please help me the figure this out.

Comment: can you add the structure of the props?

Comment: [Deep compartison arrays of objects with lodash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065663/array-of-object-deep-comparison-with-lodash)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using underscore, you could just do

```js
_.isEqual(this.props, nextProps);
```