# How to compare 2 nested json objects arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I am trying to compare 2 nested json objects arrays using **lodash**. Following example will return *true* even `obj1` and `obj2` have different number of objects inside the array.
Basically what I need to do is compare these 2 nested json objects arrays and if the arrays are identical then needs to return `true` else `false`

note :  `obj1` has **price** element and `obj2` has **countInStock** which should not use to compare

Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
import _ from "lodash"

var obj1 = [{
    "colour": {
        "value": "Black",
        "label": "Black"
    },
    "size": {
        "value": "M",
        "label": "M"
    },
    "price": "70"
},
{
    "colour": {
        "value": "Black",
        "label": "Black"
    },
    "size": {
        "value": "M",
        "label": "M"
    },
    "price": "70"
},
{
    "colour": {
        "value": "Silver",
        "label": "Silver"
    },
    "size": {
        "value": "S",
        "label": "S"
    },
    "price": "50"
},
{
    "colour": {
        "value": "Black",
        "label": "Black"
    },
    "size": {
        "value": "L",
        "label": "L"
    },
    "price": "130"
}]

var obj2 = [{
    "colour": {
        "value": "Silver",
        "label": "Silver"
    },
    "size": {
        "value": "S",
        "label": "S"
    },
    "countInStock": "3"
},
{
    "colour": {
        "value": "Black",
        "label": "Black"
    },
    "size": {
        "value": "M",
        "label": "M"
    },
    "countInStock": "10"
},
{
    "colour": {
        "value": "Black",
        "label": "Black"
    },
    "size": {
        "value": "L",
        "label": "L"
    },
    "countInStock": "3"
}]

var result = _.isEqual(
  _.omit(obj1.sort, ['price']),
  _.omit(obj2.sort, ['countInStock'])
);

console.log(result); // true
```

Comment: Try this response from a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/6950682

Comment: `_.omit(obj1.sort, ['countInStock'])` returns an empty array. That's why the result is true. What is `obj1.sort` ?

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic sorry it's should be other way around 
_.omit(obj1.sort, ['price']),
  _.omit(obj2.sort, ['countInStock'])
why it's gives an empty array?
`obj1.sort` I use this for sort the array but it's didn't work as well

Comment: Actually `obj1` and `obj2` there are NOT objects, they are arrays of objects.

Comment: @FFire Any possible solution for compare these 2 arrays of objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array of object deep comparison with lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065663/array-of-object-deep-comparison-with-lodash)

Comment: obj1.sort = `undefined`, obj2.sort is also `undefined`, so yeah they are equal.